# Reprocess or Re-Read Event hub data that read successfully

Tags: azure-eventhub

I am new to an event hub, I try to integrate using .Net Core. I am able to read the incoming event data successfully but for some reason, I want to re-read the data so is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - assuming that the data hasn't passed the [retention period](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-faq#what-is-the-maximum-retention-period-for-events-).

Events are not removed from the stream when read; they remain available for any consumer who wishes to read them until they pass the configured retention period and age out of the stream.

When connecting, Event Hub consumers request a position in the stream to start reading from, which allows them to specify any event with a known offset or sequence number.  Consumers may also begin reading at a specific point in time or request to begin at the first available event.

More information can be found in the [Reading Events](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample05_ReadingEvents.md#read-events-from-a-partition-starting-from-a-specific-date-and-time) sample for the `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs` package.